# Downloading in pdf format

Tags: asp.net

This is how I'm downloading the gridview in Excel. Pls help with the pdf download code:
 string strFileName = "Salary_Statement" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
            GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

```
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Visible = true;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Visible = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];

        }


        GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#e5e1e1");

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
            row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
        "attachment;filename=" + strFileName + ".xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

        string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();

        Response.End();
        GridView1.AllowPaging = true;//AB
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Following code shows how to download

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/317301/Code-of-Downloading-PDF-file-in-asp-net

```html
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
 

protected void ExportToPDF(GridView gvReport, bool LandScape)
    {
        int noOfColumns = 0, noOfRows = 0;
        DataTable tbl = null;
 
        if (gvReport.AutoGenerateColumns)
        {
            tbl = gvReport.DataSource as DataTable; // Gets the DataSource of the GridView Control.
            noOfColumns = tbl.Columns.Count;
            noOfRows = tbl.Rows.Count;
        }
        else
        {
            noOfColumns = gvReport.Columns.Count;
            noOfRows = gvReport.Rows.Count;
        }
 
        float HeaderTextSize = 8;
        float ReportNameSize = 10;
        float ReportTextSize = 8;
        float ApplicationNameSize = 7;
 
        // Creates a PDF document
        Document document = null;
        if (LandScape == true)
        {
            // Sets the document to A4 size and rotates it so that the orientation of the page is Landscape.
            document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 0, 0, 15, 5);
        }
        else
        {
            document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 15, 5);
        }
 
        // Creates a PdfPTable with column count of the table equal to no of columns of the gridview or gridview datasource.
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable mainTable = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable(noOfColumns);
 
        // Sets the first 4 rows of the table as the header rows which will be repeated in all the pages.
        mainTable.HeaderRows = 4;
 
        // Creates a PdfPTable with 2 columns to hold the header in the exported PDF.
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable headerTable = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable(2);
 
        // Creates a phrase to hold the application name at the left hand side of the header.
        Phrase phApplicationName = new Phrase("Sample Application", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", ApplicationNameSize, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));
 
        // Creates a PdfPCell which accepts a phrase as a parameter.
        PdfPCell clApplicationName = new PdfPCell(phApplicationName);
        // Sets the border of the cell to zero.
        clApplicationName.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
        // Sets the Horizontal Alignment of the PdfPCell to left.
        clApplicationName.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
 
        // Creates a phrase to show the current date at the right hand side of the header.
        Phrase phDate = new Phrase(DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", ApplicationNameSize, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));
 
        // Creates a PdfPCell which accepts the date phrase as a parameter.
        PdfPCell clDate = new PdfPCell(phDate);
        // Sets the Horizontal Alignment of the PdfPCell to right.
        clDate.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        // Sets the border of the cell to zero.
        clDate.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
 
        // Adds the cell which holds the application name to the headerTable.
        headerTable.AddCell(clApplicationName);
        // Adds the cell which holds the date to the headerTable.
        headerTable.AddCell(clDate);
        // Sets the border of the headerTable to zero.
        headerTable.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
 
        // Creates a PdfPCell that accepts the headerTable as a parameter and then adds that cell to the main PdfPTable.
        PdfPCell cellHeader = new PdfPCell(headerTable);
        cellHeader.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
        // Sets the column span of the header cell to noOfColumns.
        cellHeader.Colspan = noOfColumns;
        // Adds the above header cell to the table.
        mainTable.AddCell(cellHeader);
 
        // Creates a phrase which holds the file name.
        Phrase phHeader = new Phrase("Sample Export", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", ReportNameSize, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD));
        PdfPCell clHeader = new PdfPCell(phHeader);
        clHeader.Colspan = noOfColumns;
        clHeader.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
        clHeader.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        mainTable.AddCell(clHeader);
 
        // Creates a phrase for a new line.
        Phrase phSpace = new Phrase("\n");
        PdfPCell clSpace = new PdfPCell(phSpace);
        clSpace.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
        clSpace.Colspan = noOfColumns;
        mainTable.AddCell(clSpace);
 
        // Sets the gridview column names as table headers.
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++)
        {
            Phrase ph = null;
 
            if (gvReport.AutoGenerateColumns)
            {
                ph = new Phrase(tbl.Columns[i].ColumnName, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", HeaderTextSize, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD));
            }
            else
            {
                ph = new Phrase(gvReport.Columns[i].HeaderText, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", HeaderTextSize, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD));
            }
 
            mainTable.AddCell(ph);
        }
 
        // Reads the gridview rows and adds them to the mainTable
        for (int rowNo = 0; rowNo < noOfRows; rowNo++)
        {
            for (int columnNo = 0; columnNo < noOfColumns; columnNo++)
            {
                if (gvReport.AutoGenerateColumns)
                {
                    string s = gvReport.Rows[rowNo].Cells[columnNo].Text.Trim();
                    Phrase ph = new Phrase(s, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", ReportTextSize, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));
                    mainTable.AddCell(ph);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (gvReport.Columns[columnNo] is TemplateField)
                    {
                        DataBoundLiteralControl lc = gvReport.Rows[rowNo].Cells[columnNo].Controls[0] as DataBoundLiteralControl;
                        string s = lc.Text.Trim();
                        Phrase ph = new Phrase(s, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", ReportTextSize, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));
                        mainTable.AddCell(ph);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string s = gvReport.Rows[rowNo].Cells[columnNo].Text.Trim();
                        Phrase ph = new Phrase(s, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", ReportTextSize, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));
                        mainTable.AddCell(ph);
                    }
                }
            }
 
            // Tells the mainTable to complete the row even if any cell is left incomplete.
            mainTable.CompleteRow();
        }
 
        // Gets the instance of the document created and writes it to the output stream of the Response object.
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
 
        // Creates a footer for the PDF document.
        HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase(), true);
        pdfFooter.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        pdfFooter.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
 
        // Sets the document footer to pdfFooter.
        document.Footer = pdfFooter;
        // Opens the document.
        document.Open();
        // Adds the mainTable to the document.
        document.Add(mainTable);
        // Closes the document.
        document.Close();
 
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= SampleExport.pdf");
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: It is supposed to happen on a click event

Comment: Copy the content of above method in a new method and call it on click